# Firestore / Google Cloud (Default) database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have been testing an app with multi-region setup however I want to test everything with a regional database before going live.

If I have a default and non-default database under a single Firestore project, would the non-default one become default if I remove/delete the original default database?

Comparing multi-region vs regional database performance.

Comment: As far as I know deleting the (default) database won't make another database the default. That said, why would that matter for your use-case? As in: why would you want to delete (or change) the default database in order to compare performance?

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen it's because Google stated "You can use the Free quota only with the (default) database." and also Google doesn't allow changing the region of the default once it's created... Looks like my only option is to create a new project.

Comment: Yup, that seems accurate indeed. There should be a warning about not being able to change the default location of a project once you create it.